# Percentage of a row in ordered query

Tags: linq

Curious problem, not sure how to do this in linq. Part of the problem might be that I'm trying to do this all at once.

I have a phase table

```
[id, name, [order]]
{{1, 'phase 2', 2}, {2, 'phase 1', 1}
```

I'd like to get a percentage of progress through all the phases for a given phaseid.

I know of a way to do this with sql.

```
SELECT (SELECT a.row
        FROM   [phase] p 
               INNER JOIN (SELECT Row_number() 
                                    OVER( 
                                      ORDER BY [order]) row,
                                  id 
                           FROM   [phase]) p2 
                       ON p2.id = p.id 
        WHERE  p.id = @phaseid) / CONVERT(FLOAT, Count(*)) 
FROM   [phase]
```

Is there a way to do this in linq? All my attempts seem to fail

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry Hamlet, thought I'd given a good explanation.

By example.. if there are 10 phases.. and I give a phaseid which has an order order 5, I'd want it to return 0.50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var query = phases.OrderBy(x => x.Order).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
var result = query.Select((x, i) => new { x.Id, Index = i + 1 })
                  .Single(x => x.Id == phaseId).Index / (double)query.Count;
```

It first queries the IDs of all Phases from the database, already correctly ordered. In memory, it then generates the row number and filters out the phase with the requested ID.
Based on the index and the total count of phases, the percentage is then calculated.

Comment: With both of those I get the following error.

"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Double] Select[Phase,Double](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[PHRestService.Phase], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[PHRestService.Phase,System.Int32,System.Double]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Is this because I'm using LINQ to Entities?

Comment: @PaulHutchinson: That's a pity. It looks like EF doesn't support that particular method :(

Comment: @Dantheman I got there just a bit before you using your methodology. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PaulHutchinson: Good job! :-)

Answer (score 0):

First thing I got working for anybody tackling this problem in the future. vb.net

```
Dim query = (From p2 In db.Phases Order By p2.Order).AsEnumerable().Select(Function(p2, index) New test With {.id = p2.ID, .row = index + 1})
Dim Percentage = query.Where(Function(x) x.id = 3).Select(Function(x) x.row).First / db.Phases.Count
```